# Does MySQL REALLY not support date formatted @variables?

Tags: mysql

I am an experienced SQL Server developer working on a Mysql  project.  I just can’t believe that Mysql does not support @variables in date format!!!  Although I see (bottom) what’s in the documentation, because of I’ve designed a query to hold the first date of activity for each customer in an @var, I’m still tempted to try:

```
set @mydate = STR_TO_DATE('Dec/15/2008', '%M/%d/%Y');
select @mydate;
```

but I get a value of BLOB, which I gather is Mysql’s way of punting.

So I ask, does the following REALLY mean no date formatted @vars? Why would MYSQL be designed this way?? Where is the code for @vars in the MYSQL source?:

from MYSQL doc:
User defined variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but running your two lines on MySQL 5.0.51a gives me `2008-12-15`.

Comment: your resopnse was very helpful, led me to the fact that the query works from the command line , but not from mysql workbench (returns blob) or from toad (returns excluded)...any thoughts as to why these IDE's have trouble with date formatted @vars?

Comment: query works in mysql query browser and command line, but not in workbench or toad

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but drove me nuts! It returns `Blob` in workbench but throws a collation error from the command line.

You need to cast the field as date - using date_format seems to mess with the data type.

E.g.

```
SET @StartDate := CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AS Date);  -- start of the month
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work (char seems to be less problematic)

```
set @mydate = cast( STR_TO_DATE('Dec/15/2008', '%M/%d/%Y') as char);
```

or to keep the original `datetime`

```
set @mydate = cast( STR_TO_DATE('Dec/15/2008', '%M/%d/%Y') as datetime);
```

Comment: this works and could be very helpful - but then i would have to cast it back when i write it back out to the database.... since i'll be doing this a lot it would get annoying .... i will check if i can make it work this way later this morning

Comment: Why are you casting this to `char`? A date type would be more appropriate surely? @Gary - I find these casts are always necessary when using functions in SQL Workbench.

Comment: But you can still do `cast( STR_TO_DATE('Dec/15/2008', '%M/%d/%Y') as datetime)` or whatever

Comment: I don't think workbench will return correctly for type datetime